# Datatables serverside .draw() request succeeds but does not update

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using Datatables `v1.10.20` with serverside processing, and when I try to fire `myTable.draw();` it registers the request makes the ajax call and the response is also valid json, but the table doesn't get updated.

The table is loading fine the first time, its only when I try to trigger it via js, the above issue is occuring.

I've tried the following methods

```
myTable.ajax.reload();
myTable.draw();
```

Both of which do work as in ajax call is sent, but the table is not refreshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found that the value for the `draw` param was hardcoded in the server-side(*by someone else ofc* :) ), and ideally that should be passed exactly what was received in the request, due to which no matter what you do, if the value for `draw` doesn't change, datatable doesn't think its worth updating the table. Once I updated the logic it started working flawlessly.

Got the solution from [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/35591/draw-does-not-refresh-datatable-what-i-have-to-see-in-my-code)